# Order columns in ascending order

Tags: python, csv

I have this function:

```
import csv
import operator

def fst_func():
    try:
        with open('Mycsv.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for i,row in enumerate(reader):
                print(row['1st row'], row['2nd row'], row['3rd row'], row['4th row'], row['5th row'])
                if(i >= 4):
                    break
    except:
        print("Non existent file")
```

This function, prints all data from those rows, but, only the first 5 occurences.

Now, I need to sort the print, in ascending order, meaning, the `2nd row` has records of `float` type, so I need not just print those 5 occurrences, but sort them by this row, in ascending order.

Any ideas regarding this?

**EDIT**

So, column 2nd, has float-like records on it, it could look like this:

```
100.00
200.00
3000.00
2
17
```

So, the correct order, regardless of other columns, should be:

```
2
17
100.00
200.00
3000.00
```

How can I sort it this way, given the above code?

**EDIT 2**

So, this is the actual output:

```
['23950.00', '64', 'My Services ltd', 'Movilnet App', '550']
['20', '6600.00', 'My company Ltd', 'Some', 'Santander']
['12250.00', '25', 'Palms', 'Chase Manhattan', 'Bank Ltd.']
['25', '9500.00', 'BsAs', 'My company App.', 'Your LTD']
['', '12000.00', '25', 'My company', 'Other Ltd']
```

It should be:

```
['20', '6600.00', 'My company Ltd', 'Some', 'Santander']
['25', '9500.00', 'BsAs', 'My company App.', 'Your LTD']
['', '12000.00', '25', 'My company', 'Other Ltd']
['12250.00', '25', 'Palms', 'Chase Manhattan', 'Bank Ltd.']
['23950.00', '64', 'My Services ltd', 'Movilnet App', '550']
```

So, the float records on 2nd column should be sorted in ascending order, I hope this explains my situation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you want with an example input and desired output.

Comment: Hi @martineau it's edited, please, have a look, thank you

Comment: Sorry, the edit really doesn't help very much - I meant a few lines/rows of the input file and what would be printed from them if it was sorted. Your question is confusing because you seem to be mixing-up the terms "rows" and "columns". CSV files are organized in rows composed of columns of data, so writing `row['1st row'], row['2nd row'], ...` seems like it really ought to be `row['1st column'], row['2nd column'], ...`.

Comment: I'm so sorry, yes, you are right, gotta put some expected output so You can see what I mean

Comment: Edited, I hope this clarifies my situation. It's a bit confusing indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does basically what what you want (which is to order the rows by what's in their second column).

1. It reads the specified number of rows in from the the file.
2. Sorts them by the numerical value of their second column.
3. Prints the now sorted results.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter


def fst_func(filename, numrows=4):
    rows = []
    try:
        with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
                rows.append(row)
                if i >= numrows:
                    break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("file {!r} does not exist".format(filename))
        return

    rows.sort(key=lambda row: float(itemgetter('2nd row')(row)))
    for row in rows:
        print(', '.join(row.values()))

fst_func('My_csv.csv')
```

Here's the contents of the input file I used for testing:

```
1st row,2nd row,3rd row,4th row,5th row
23950.00,64,My Services ltd,Movilnet App,550
20,6600.00,My company Ltd,Some,Santander
12250.00,25,Palms,Chase Manhattan,Bank Ltd.
25,9500.00,BsAs,My company App.,Your LTD
,12000.00,25,My company,Other Ltd
```

And here's what was printed:

```
12250.00, 25, Palms, Chase Manhattan, Bank Ltd.
23950.00, 64, My Services ltd, Movilnet App, 550
20, 6600.00, My company Ltd, Some, Santander
25, 9500.00, BsAs, My company App., Your LTD
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, I think you want to know how to sort your row in ascending order

For this problem you can use that

```
def fst_func():
try:
    with open('Mycsv.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for i,row in enumerate(reader):
            rowlist = [row['1st row'], row['2nd row'], row['3rd row'], row['4th row'], row['5th row']]
            print(sorted(rowlist))
            if(i >= 4):
                break
```

Comment: Hi, just edited my question, could You please have a look? Thank You very much